# Gradle test tasks with webcontext fails to use entities

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, gradle, testng

I have an issue with some gradle task that should run tests. Since this is some legacy from ant tasks we do not want to include them into our test suite. Especially considering that those ant ones are in testng, and those made by us, and used on regular basis are made using spock and junit.

The problem is that those tests are using some context which works pretty well when I run those tests under eclipse IDE, but it fails if I try to do sth like:

```
task testNgTesting(type: Test, dependsOn: testClasses){
    useTestNG()
    includes = ["**/*IT*"]
}
```

But when I try to use that task I get errors like "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:" or "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name"

Comment: Try `includes ['**/*IT*']` or `include '**/*IT*'`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I mean context is running, and tests are running either. The problem is that they are failing with the message above.

Comment: I'd expect that you're missing some resources required to run your tests. These should be mapped to `sourceSets { test { resources { srcDir ... } } }`

Comment: @Radim finally I've found some help in the internet, and obviously it was missing some resources. The issue was discussed on gradle dev forum, they are aware of problem, but did not come to any conclusion on how do they want to fix it. Anyway the workaround I've found is in my answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is deeper. Gradle is trying to be smart and from whatever folder it has defined it puts classes files into classes folder, and all the other files into resources. When persistence.xml is loaded it scans for annotated entities starting with classpath root for folder it is present in (i.e. build/resources/main). Since all those classes are in build/classes/main it fails to find them. The workaround I've made is introduce two copy tasks. one named is copying persistence.xml into classes folder, and another is moving this file back to resources after the tests are finished. You might want to use something like
testNgTesting.finalizedBy(cleanAfterIntegrationTests) to make sure the cleanup occurs even if there are some tests that fails.